# wget doesn't see/download certain files?

Tags: wget

I am trying to download all files starting with `traceroute` from https://data-store.ripe.net/datasets/atlas-daily-dumps/ via wget.

I am running the following command:

`wget -A traceroute* -m -np https://data-store.ripe.net/datasets/atlas-daily-dumps/ --no-check-certificate`

It creates the directories, checks index.html's and then within 5 minutes it stops, without downloading any traceroute files.

When I try another type of file via

`wget -A connection* -m -np https://data-store.ripe.net/datasets/atlas-daily-dumps/ --no-check-certificate`

it donwloads the `connection` files no problem. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a local file that matches the glob `traceroute*`; you need to put single quotes around it so the shell won't match anything:

```
wget -A 'traceroute*' -m -np https://data-store.ripe.net/datasets/atlas-daily-dumps/ --no-check-certificate
```

Answer (score -1):

specifying `traceroute*.bz2` seems to have fixed the problem